# Is it possible to add music to the timeline while animating?

Tags: animation, audio

Basically I want to try to make an animation where a character plays a song on an instrument. Is there a way to get the audio to the timeline so I can listen where the music is going (seeing the waveform also helps)? This is pretty much mandatory so I can time everything correctly while animating. Also begin able to match the grid spacing with the BPM of the song would also be huge help.

Comment: @Lutzi When you find something to be a duplicate question, you should vote to close it.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Which I did.

Comment: @Lutzi Yep, sorry I just realised somehow the number of close votes are not shown to me, don't know why.

Comment: Hello, SCCCCC, this does seem to be a duplicate question. If the linked answers in the commentary don't work for you, for any reason, just edit your question with reference to them explaining why not, and we'll happily re-open for you.